# Swift - Execution of methods not proceeding

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I developed three functions within my VC and they are as following:

1. checkUsernameOrEmailTaken(..)
2. checkEmailTaken(..)
3. checkUsernameTaken(..)

The first one, i.e. checkUsernameOrEmailTaken calls the other two within itself, and returns a result through completion that indicates which one is taken (based on int value where 1 = email taken and 2= username taken. Here is the code:

```
func checkUsernameOrEmailTaken(username: String, email:String, completion: (result: Int) -> Void)
    {
        /*This function checks the result of both functions, checkEmailTaken and checkUsernameTaken*/
        /*
            return 1 = email is taken
            return 2 = username is taken
        */
        var inputTaken:Int = 0
        print("Inside CheckUsernameOrEmailTaken")
        self.checkEmailTaken(email, completion: { (result)->Void in
            print("Finish Checking Email Taken")
            if(result == true)
            {
                /*Email is taken*/
                print("Email Taken")
                inputTaken = 1
                completion(result: inputTaken)
            }else{
                /*Email not taken*/
                print("Email Available")
                self.checkUsernameTaken(username, completion: { (result)->Void in
                    if(result == true)
                    {
                        inputTaken = 2
                        completion(result: inputTaken)
                    }else{
                        completion(result: 0)
                    }
                })
            }

        })

    }

    func checkEmailTaken(email:String, completion: (result: Bool) -> Void)
    {
        print("Inside CheckEmailTaken")
        //let reference = Firebase(url:"https://something.firebaseio.com/users/")
        reference.queryOrderedByChild("email").queryEqualToValue("\(email)").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
            if (snapshot.value["email"] != nil) {
                print("Inside CheckEmailTaken ---- Taken")
                completion(result: true)
            }else{
                print("Inside CheckEmailTaken ----- Available")
                completion(result: false)
            }
        })
    }

    func checkUsernameTaken(username: String, completion: (result: Bool) -> Void)
    {
        //let reference = Firebase(url:"https://something.firebaseio.com/users/")
        reference.queryOrderedByChild("username").queryEqualToValue("\(username)").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
            if (snapshot.value["username"] != nil) {
                completion(result: true)
            }else{
                completion(result: false)
            }
        })
    }
```

I have many print statement to know until where the execution proceeded. I only get in the console:

```
Inside CheckUsernameOrEmailTaken
Inside CheckEmailTaken
```

and I have progress spinner that doesn't disappear because the call didn't proceed. It seems as if it is continuing execution but no action showing. In the backend, I have

```
->users
  ->6dd077ac-dsds-4060-ac4f-dsdsdsdsdsds1
 email: "kleina@outlook.com"
 mobile: "32322332"
 name: "Kleina"
 username: "someone"
```

My input in text field is different email but same username i.e. someone...and it keeps going on. If I try to test for email existence, it works and shows that email is taken. please let me know where am going wrong...first functions I write using Firebase..

Comment: I would set a breakpoint and step through the code to see where it hangs up. Is the Firebase connection established successfully?

Comment: @blacksheep_2011 how can I check that it is? As I said first code really for me

Comment: You need to learn how to use the Xcode debugger which allows you to set breakpoints and step through your code at runtime to see the values of your variables in order to debug logic problems and crashes. I recommend you follow a tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: @RoboticCat thanks for the advice although you assumed don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Please also insert error blocks on the Firebase queries to see if something is wrong:

```
ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    println(snapshot.value)
}, withCancelBlock: { error in
  println(error.description)
})
```

You also should get an error when there is no connection to the db.

Comment: Added the error block...still it doesn't proceed far enough to go there...it only shows the same print statements in original post.

Comment: Have you tried to set a breakpoint and step through the code?

Comment: Will try in a bit moving between locations  and let you know

Comment: I used the breakpoints and it reaches to reference.queryOrderedByChild("email").queryEqualToValue("\(email)") then skips to withCancelBlock but never prints whats in it

Comment: has error a value? set the breakpoint to the println line and then type in the console `po error`

Comment: No it doesn't execute that line I used breakpoint but it doesn't execute that line..@blacksheep_2011

Comment: I think thats not the error but I think you can write `queryEqualToValue("\(email)")` as `queryEqualToValue(email)` and the same for username.

Comment: really weird ...did much more of this in Parse but it all worked fine...in addition the documentation of Firebase is really confusing and no where near Parse quality

Comment: Note that the error block was not the only change. @blacksheep_2011 also changed the code to use `.Value`. A `.ChildAdded` will only fire *when* a child is added. A `.Value` event will fire with `nil` if there is no current value. Since you want to detect the existence/non-existence of a value, you should use `.Value`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I changed it to Value and it worked. Post it as answer and I will select it. Thanks,

Comment: @blacksheep_2011 already uses `.Value` in his answer, I just called it out. If that change made it work, accept his answer please.